# Teamcity: Is there any REST API to get scheduled builds?

Tags: api, teamcity

Looking for Teamcity Rest API that can provide me schedule details for a build config.

If the build is scheduled to run every 8 hours in a day. I should get list  at what time the builds are scheduled to run for next 7 days?

(like 11 Aug 00:00, 08:00, 16:00, 12 Aug 00:00, 08:00, and so on)